# Click on any link or button redirects to another page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net web app project which includes total three pages i.e. login page, front page and a page for grid view. When i run the application, it works normally, But when I click any link or any button, it directs to first page. I created even new page also for gird View but still the issue persists. I don't know the issue is in grid view or database. Please assist me in this regards as I have worked a lot on this project.

Here is the code for First page to which it is being redirected again and again

```
<asp:Content ID="FormContentHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div id="logobar">
                <h1>
                    <img src="http://localhost:50090/uploads/icons/logo.png" style="height: 99px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Document Expiry Alert System</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div id="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div id="icons">
                        <div>
                            <a href="DatabaseGView.aspx">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/icons/update.png" /></a>
                            <a href="DatabaseGView.aspx">Update</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="text-left">
                            <h1>Students Database</h1>
                        </div>
                        <table class="">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="" style="width: 30%">Registration No.</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="ID" runat="server" Width="190px" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="" style="width: 30%">First Name</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="FN" runat="server" Width="190px" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Last Name</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="LN" runat="server" Width="190px" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Nationality</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Country1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8" Width="190px">
/--Here was very long list of countries so i removed--/
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Email</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8" TextMode="Email" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Passport No</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="passportNo" runat="server" Width="190px" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Place of Issue</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="PlaceOfIssue" runat="server" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8" Width="190px">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="AF">Afghanistan</asp:ListItem>
/--Here was very long list of countries so i removed--/
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Issue</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="issue" runat="server" TextMode="Date" Width="190px" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Expiry</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Expiry" runat="server" Width="190px" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Visa No</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="VisaNo" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8" runat="server" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Visa Expiry</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="VisaExpiry" runat="server" Width="190px" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">Emirates ID No</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="EmiratesNo" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8" runat="server" Width="190px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">ID Expiry</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="EmiaratesExpiry" runat="server" Width="190px" TextMode="Date" CssClass="form-control box-margin-8"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="">&nbsp; </td>
                                <td class="" style="text-align: inherit; font-family: 'Arial Black'; overflow: auto; width: 190px;">
                                    <asp:Button ID="submitt" runat="server" class="btn" OnClick="submitt_Click" Text="Submit" />
                                    <input id="Reset1" type="button" value="reset" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the second page:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DatabaseGView.aspx.cs" Inherits="Document_Expiry_Reminder.DatabaseGView" %>

<asp:Content ID="FormContentHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container">
        <div class="img-responsive" style="background-color: none;">
            <h1>
                <img src="http://localhost:50090/uploads/icons/logo.png" style="height: 99px" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Student Database Administration</h1>
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
            <div>
                <hr />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="displayflex">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <a href="FrontPage.aspx">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="uploads/icons/add.png" /></a>
                    <a href="FrontPage.aspx">Add</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 5px">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Select Document</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Passport Expiry</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Visa &amp; Emirates Expiry</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;From Date
            <asp:TextBox ID="fromDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp; To Date&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="toDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="Search" runat="server" OnClick="Search_Click" Text="Search" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView  ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Reg No" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FN" HeaderText="First" SortExpression="FN" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LN" HeaderText="Last" SortExpression="LN" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Country1" HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="email" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PassportNo" HeaderText="Passport" SortExpression="PassportNo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PlaceOfIssue" HeaderText="Place Of Issue" SortExpression="PlaceOfIssue" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Issue" HeaderText="Issue" SortExpression="Issue" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expiry" HeaderText="Expiry" SortExpression="Expiry" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VisaNo" HeaderText="Visa" SortExpression="VisaNo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VisaExpiry" HeaderText="Visa Expiry" SortExpression="VisaExpiry" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmiratesNo" HeaderText="Emirates ID" SortExpression="EmiratesNo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmiratesExpiry" HeaderText="ID Expiry" SortExpression="EmiratesExpiry" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="#0033CC" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" BorderStyle="Groove" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys" BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SzabistStudentsConnectionString3 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Students] WHERE [ID] = @original_ID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Students] ([ID], [FN], [LN], [Country1], [gender], [email], [PassportNo], [PlaceOfIssue], [Issue], [Expiry], [VisaNo], [VisaExpiry], [EmiratesNo], [EmiratesExpiry]) VALUES (@ID, @FN, @LN, @Country1, @gender, @email, @PassportNo, @PlaceOfIssue, @Issue, @Expiry, @VisaNo, @VisaExpiry, @EmiratesNo, @EmiratesExpiry)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Students]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Students] SET [FN] = @FN, [LN] = @LN, [Country1] = @Country1, [gender] = @gender, [email] = @email, [PassportNo] = @PassportNo, [PlaceOfIssue] = @PlaceOfIssue, [Issue] = @Issue, [Expiry] = @Expiry, [VisaNo] = @VisaNo, [VisaExpiry] = @VisaExpiry, [EmiratesNo] = @EmiratesNo, [EmiratesExpiry] = @EmiratesExpiry WHERE [ID] = @original_ID" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="String" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PassportNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PlaceOfIssue" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Issue" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Expiry" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VisaNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="VisaExpiry" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EmiratesNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EmiratesExpiry" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="FN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LN" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country1" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="gender" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PassportNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PlaceOfIssue" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Issue" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="Expiry" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="VisaNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="VisaExpiry" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="EmiratesNo" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EmiratesExpiry" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_ID" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

From the second page, any click on link or button it redirects to fronpage.aspx which is firts page in my project

Comment: How can we help you without seeing the code, do you think?

Comment: Sir, I have uploaded the code, Please assist

Comment: These links: `<a href="FrontPage.aspx">Add</a>` will clearly direct to the front page. That is to be expected. I can also see two buttons on the second page, called "Search", which each call a different code-behind method when clicked. What is in those methods? Something which would cause a redirect? You should also check your Page_Load method, and any events which are handled in your Master Page, to see if they contain redirection code. If you are unsure what is happening, set breakpoints in your code to find the moment when the redirection happens. If you're still unsure, post the code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the form tag in master page, maybe it has action set to frontpage.aspx